# Como mostrar NULL em campos onde a condição não é satisfeita no SQL

Tags: sql, condição, null

Tenho essa tabela de Entrada (p):

```
EmployeeID  EventId     EntityId    EnterDate
11111       100         1           2:54:11
11111       100         1           2:54:43
11111       100         1           2:56:03
11111       100         1           2:56:35
11111       100         1           2:58:51
```

E essa tabela de Saida (q):

```
EmployeeID  EventId     EntityId    ExitDate
11111       100         3           2:52:46
11111       100         3           2:53:29
11111       100         3           2:55:15
11111       100         3           2:57:33
11111       100         3           2:58:15
11111       100         3           6:26:08
```

Com esse código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT u.EmployeeId, CAST(p.DeviceTS AS Date) AS Day, p.DeviceTS AS EnterDate, MIN(q.DeviceTS) AS ExitDate
FROM            (SELECT        a.DeviceTS, a.UserId
                      FROM            dbo.DeviceLog AS a INNER JOIN
                                                dbo.Users AS u ON a.UserId = u.Id
                      WHERE        (a.EventId = 100) AND (a.EntityId IN (1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 20, 25, 27))) AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT        a.DeviceTS, a.UserId
                           FROM            dbo.DeviceLog AS a INNER JOIN
                                                     dbo.Users AS u ON a.UserId = u.Id
                           WHERE        (a.EventId = 100) AND (a.EntityId IN (3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 21, 26, 28))) AS q ON p.UserId = q.UserId AND CAST(p.DeviceTS AS Date) = CAST(q.DeviceTS AS Date) AND 
                     q.DeviceTS > p.DeviceTS INNER JOIN
                     dbo.Users AS u ON p.UserId = u.Id AND u.EmployeeId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.EmployeeId, p.DeviceTS
ORDER BY u.EmployeeId, EnterDate, ExitDate
```

Retorna esse resultado:

```
    EmployeeId    EnterDate    ExitDate
1   11111         2:54:11      2:55:15
2   11111         2:54:43      2:55:15
3   11111         2:56:03      2:57:33
4   11111         2:56:35      2:57:33
5   11111         2:58:51      6:26:08
```

Queria fazer para que quando houvesse duas entradas ou duas saidas seguidas representasse o valor como null como a seguinte tabela:

```
    EmployeeId    EnterDate    ExitDate
1   11111         NULL         2:52:46
2   11111         NULL         2:53:29
3   11111         2:54:11      NULL
4   11111         2:54:43      2:55:15
5   11111         2:56:03      NULL
6   11111         2:56:35      2:57:33
7   11111         NULL         2:58:15
8   11111         2:58:51      6:26:08
```

Teria como fazer isso?
Obs: Não consigo utilizar IF, CASE, etc.

Comment: Desculpe, mas eu não entendi o motivo de ser uma duplicata. Poderia me explicar o que estaria errado ou como eu poderia utilizar isso para solucionar meu problema?

Comment: Se quer resultados em que não haja correspondência dos dois lados, o Join nao pode ser Inner. Vide gráficos e respostas do link acima. INNER não retorna casos onde um lado esteja nulo.

Comment: O Inner é usado apenas para pegar o employeeid, nesse, não vai ter nulo, para a comparação do EnterDate e ExitDate foi utilizado o Left Outer Join